# Display value from "input range" in another element gives "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

This has been asked before, but I have found no solid, working, plain JS solution, all solutions out there are using frameworks or just do not work.

I simply want to get the value of a input "range" values and have them displayed in a span element.

I get undefined with no error in the console.

Here is the JS code:

```
document.getElementById("height").addEventListener("input", 
sliderChange(this.value));

function sliderChange(val) {
document.getElementById('yourHeight').innerHTML = val;
}
```

Further, I want to store the user input and use for another function to calculate the final results(this function is not there yet).

Here is the link:

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/ZyRogX

Comment: I think you can replace your id="height" to someother name, as height is an attribute.

Comment: I agree this was not best convention, it was just a first draft, but it's interesting to see that it did not matter o0:-)

Comment: Haha yea . I was also thinking the same,HTML is excluding these things after all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code `document.getElementById("height").addEventListener("input", sliderChange(this.value))`, `this` refers to the global `window` object and not the input, that's why `this.value` is `undefined`.

You need to pass a `listener` callback function to the `addEventListener` so it will have its own scope and `this` will refer to your `input`:

```
document.getElementById("height").addEventListener("input", function(){ sliderChange(this.value)} );
```

This is the [updated **working Demo**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEGGXq).

Comment: Thanks so much, I usually always add a callback to a dom level 3 listener, this is almost embarassing, I have always believed I could call the function straight up, just never tried it. Believe it would not matter. Just as an extra, can these range input fields be handled with "target.event"?

Comment: @ptts Yes you can use `event.target` using `function(e){ sliderChange(e.target.value)}`, and you can always call the function directly if you won't use `this`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass a function to `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById("height").addEventListener("input", function() { sliderChange(this.value) });
```